# Using @Conditional Spring annotation without knowing the whole property name

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I want to optionally enable a `@Configuration`, based on whether a type of `application.properties` property exists or not. However I will **not** know the whole property name in advance, only part of its prefix i.e.

```
spring.security.oauth2.<provider-name>.url=x.y.z
```

And the goal is to enable the configuration using something like:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.security", value="oauth2.*")
```

or something like that but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried multiple combinations, none work it always expects the full property name but I don't know the `<provider-name>` in advance. Any ways to achieve this functionality?

Comment: You can create your own `@Conditional` implementation and filter the properties you need searching for a `prefix` and do what you need to do if it's present.

Comment: Yes, I just did that but still looking for something out of the box. If no one posts I'll post the solution here

Comment: Well, that's the solution. There's nothing out of the box that does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of right now Spring does not support the requested functionality with the out of the box annotations which means a custom `@Conditional` condition must be created that does what we want. The `Condition` implementation looks like this:

```
public class EnableOAuth2Condition implements Condition {
  @Override
  public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    Environment env = context.getEnvironment();
    for(Iterator it = ((AbstractEnvironment) env).getPropertySources().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
      PropertySource propertySource = (PropertySource) it.next();
      if (propertySource instanceof MapPropertySource) {
        for (String propertyName : ((MapPropertySource) propertySource).getSource().keySet()) {
          if(propertyName.startsWith("spring.security.oauth2")) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

and the way to use it on a `@Configuration` class is the following:

```
@Configuration
@Conditional(EnableOAuth2Condition.class)
public class MyOAuth2Config {
  ...
}
```

A bit messy for something simple but that's the way to go for now.

Answer (score 0):

To improve on @Pentakon answer, few more additions that we can do:

1. Create our own annotation to hold the prefix

   ```
    @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
    public @interface PropertyPrefix {

        String value(); 
    }
   ```
2. Use this on in your configuration class

   ```
    @PropertyPrefix("redis")
    @Conditional(PropertyPrefixPresentCondition.class)
   ```
3. And the implementation of PropertyPrefixPresentCondition

   ```
   public class PropertyPrefixPresentCondition implements Condition {

     @Override
     public boolean matches(@NotNull ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
         var prefix = metadata.getAnnotations()
            .get(PropertyPrefix.class)
            .getValue("value")
            .map(Object::toString)
            .orElse(null);
         if (StringUtils.isEmpty(prefix)) {
             throw new IllegalStateException("Prefix must be present");
         }
         var env = context.getEnvironment();
         for (PropertySource<?> source : ((AbstractEnvironment) env).getPropertySources()) {
             if (source instanceof MapPropertySource mapPropertySource) {
                 for (String propertyName : mapPropertySource.getSource().keySet()) {
                     if (propertyName.startsWith(prefix)) {
                         return true;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return false;
     }
   }
   ```